# Asp.net LinkedIn company feed

Tags: asp.net, linkedin-api

I'm looking for an .net web application that displays a LinkedIn company feed to an mvc or aspx web page that I can style the rendering. Does anyone know of an open source project that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for LinkedIn C# driver/open source packages, I would recommend write one yourselves. You will have the control over the API calls and can explore the api possibilities to the max based on your requirement.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates

URL for pagination : [https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?event-type=status-update&count={0}&start={1}](https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/%7Bid%7D/updates?event-type=status-update&count=%7B0%7D&start=%7B1%7D)